# How to get percentage from a running clock divided by a specified variable java

Tags: java, time, percentage, chronometer

i have this code where variable date3 from a datepicker dialog.

```
    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int hour2, int minute2) {
        hour2final = hour2;
        minute2final = minute2;

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance ();
        c.setTimeInMillis ( 0 );
        c.set ( year2final, month2final, day2final, hour2final, minute2final, 0 );
        date2 = c.getTimeInMillis ();
        difference = date2 - date1;

        Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance ();
        c1.setTimeInMillis ( 0 );
        c1.set ( year2final, month2final - 1, day2final, hour2final, minute2final, 0 );
        date3 = c1.getTimeInMillis ();
        difference3 = date3 - date;
        ondatecountdowntext3 ();
```

and this code on my chronometer (as a count up timer)

```
private void starttimercu() {

    cupti.setBase ( SystemClock.elapsedRealtime () );
    cupti.start ();
    ondatecountdowntext3 ();

    cupti.setOnChronometerTickListener ( new Chronometer.OnChronometerTickListener () {
        @Override
        public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer chronometer) {
            t1 = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime () - chronometer.getBase ();
            t2 = date3;
            percentage = t1*100/t2;
            tvp.setText ( percentage+"%" );

        }
    } );


}
```

t1 is the time when the chronometer start and running, and t2(date3) is the total amount of time in millis until the chronometer running until 100%. Problem is when i try to divide t1 (running time) and t2(date3"total time") the percentage in texview tvp did not run as i want it to be. It stuck on 0% and not increasing. Anyone have any solutions?.

Comment: If t2 is an integer, then your fraction 't1*100/t2' is an integer division. Are you aware of that ? Other idea : t1 should be multiplied by 1000, not 100 (t1 is a millisecond value).

Comment: is t2 is an interger if t2 = date3 ? just to clarify because date3 = c1.getTimeInMillis (); and it should is millisecond. Correct me if i`m wrong. Anyway yes, *100 should be 1000, i just noticed it.

Comment: I don't know where `.getTimeInMillis()` is coming from, but for `System.currentTimeMillis()` it returns a long. So `t2` will be a long/int. Then by dividing by `t2` you'll get a long/int. In other words, the quantity by which you divide a number will define the type of the result (`1/2 -> int` and `1/2.0 -> double`).

Comment: the problem is the value of fraction of the percentage is not an int/long value thus it stuck on on int/long value (0). So t1,t2 and percentage  should be in double/float value. Just realize that. Thanks bro, it solved the problem.